# Symfony @Assert\Type("string") validation passes with integer value

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have a problem with validation of a field of type string in symfony 4. Here is an example:

```
<?php

class Foo {
    
    /**
     * @Assert\NotNull
     * @Assert\Type("string")
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected string $uid;
}
```

And when I send (PUT) request like this it passes:

```
{
    "uid": 5,
}
```

The validation is working the other way around. If I set the field to integer and pass some string like "test" is properly validated.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it correctly. What happens if you post "test" as a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is due to the fact that integers are automatically interpreted as strings when used as strings in PHP. You will want to use a [regex constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html), the example in the docs does what you want. Something like this:

```
<?php

class Foo {
    
    /**
     * @Assert\NotNull
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *     pattern="/\d/",
     *     match=false,
     *     message="Your name cannot contain a number"
     * )
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected string $uid;
}
```